# CoreData with @FetchRequest (SwiftUI) and NSPredicate crashes if there is no data

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsfetchrequest

I have a SwiftUI app where I am using `@FetchRequest` along with a predicate. Everything works fine as long as there is already some data.

However, when the app is first installed and the user tries to perform a search before entering any data, the app crashes with this error:

`error: SQLCore dispatchRequest: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x60000188c380> , unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (username CONTAINS[cd] "r") with userInfo of (null)`

I believe the cause of the problem is that the column doesn't exist (because there is no data). What I'd like to do is pass `nil` for the predicate in the case where this is no data.

I understand how to use `NSManagedObjectContext` and `count(for:)` but the context isn't really made available via the `@EnvironmentObject` at the time I need to use it. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to handle this. I don't see how a `try-catch` would work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do have a solution. Its not pretty, but it does work. Because the `NSManagedObjectContext` is being passed around via `@Environment` it isn't initialized when a SwiftUI `View` `init` is being run. So to get the context you can do:

`if let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {`

and make the call to get the count in there.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm clueless sometimes. I did not read the error thoroughly since it happened in the context of something I was changing so I thought the problem was that. But no, that is not the problem.

The problem is that earlier in the day, I *renamed* a column from `username` to something else. But I forgot to change the `NSPredicate`.

So for the sake of anyone else using SwiftUI and `@FetchRequest`, if you do need to count the number of items, you will need to revert to `NSFetchRequest` to do it. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.